# Subversion pre-commit error message isn't shown in stash bitbucket svn mirror tool

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Our main repository system is on a subversion server. In the near future we want to move to git. Our developers want to use the functionalities and features of git, but they have to do their commits in subversion. For this we implemented a stash instance.

For a commit in our subversion repository a few steps are required:

1. Clone repository from git
2. make your changes and commit into git
3. finally merge your commits into subversion using Atlassian Stash with "**BitBucket Subversion Mirror Plugin v3.0.0**"

And here is the problem:

If for some reason a commit into our subversion repository is blocked by the pre-commit script of the subversion there is no error message shown in stash. Making a normal svn commit without using stash, the error message is shown.

**svn pre-commit script**

```
echo "error message" 1>&2
exit 100
```

**Error message in Atlassian Stash (but without error message):**

```
The pull request merged without conflicts, but updating master was canceled by a plugin.

    Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 100) with output:
```

I've tried to put the error log on *stdout* and on *stderr*. But nothing is shown in stash.

Is there someone tried this behaviour and had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. We've managed to reproduce it now working on the fix. There is an issue you may track at (https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SG-160) - please expect build with a fix in about week.

Thanks!

Comment: Tested it with version 3.0.1 and it works now. Thanks